# Processing email queue in Windows Server 2008

Tags: email, smtp, windows-server-2008-r2

Hi
I have a Windows Server 2008 R2 VPS that I have just installed the SMTP service on.  I can send emails through telnet to smtp (telnet localhost 25) but from my asp.net application, emails reach the outgoing queue and just sit there.

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to what might cause this behaviour?

Thanks